# Need lookup functionality for lightning Datatable

Tags: lightning

I am working on inline editing in the lightning datatable & i want to enable the lookup functionality in one of the field of the object , like i have Task object under Task object there is "Assigned to" field. currently it is showing as a Static field , please let me know how can i enable this functionality in the aura component.

Thanks

Comment: are you using lightning:datatable?

Comment: Yes , using lightning:datatable , in " Assigned to" field  under Task objecti want look up functionality .

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, currently lightning:datatable doesn't support Lookup functionality out of the box - https://trailblazer.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=0873A000000TsQFQA0

If you really want you might want to consider creating your own column type via LWC

Comment: yeah that i know , that's the reason only i m looking for help , any other way to get this done , any links or code available ?